# Magento 2 : Problem extending a Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, di

I have an error on `bin/magento setup:di:compile` on my module:

> MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class
>   A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option because the
>   name is already in use in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/A/Cust/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php
>   on line 7

My Files :

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="A_Cust" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option" type="A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option" />
</config>
```

**A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options;

    use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option;

    class Option extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option
    {
        /**
         * Class constructor
         */
        public function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/edit/options/option.phtml');
        }

        public function getTemplatesHtml()
        {
          ... 
        } 

        public function getOptionValues()
        {
          ...
        }

    }
```

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line `use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option;`

```
<?php
    namespace A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options;



    class Option extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option
    {
        /**
         * Class constructor
         */
        public function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/edit/options/option.phtml');
        }

        public function getTemplatesHtml()
        {
... 
        } 

        public function getOptionValues()
        {
...
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank for your answer. when I remove the line I have another error : Class 'A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/A/Cust/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php on line 5

Comment: @Alexglvr update the code their was \ missing in start

Comment: Thanks, it compiles now... My custom product option page does not display defined options any more now... and don't work...I have to search why now (next step). Going from magento 1 to magento 2 is not so easy... Thanks  Again

Comment: @Alexglvr if you find this answer helpful kindly accept it. you are missing the point here don't stick with  magento1 `$this->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/edit/options/option.phtml');`  just add ` protected `$_template = 'Namespace_Modulename::product/edit/options/option.phtml;` in your class

Comment: I still have no options displayed in backend product Custom options as soon as I add the     <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option" type="A\Cust\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option" /> in di.xml... As soon as I remove this line, my product options appear...I also wanted to define my phtmls in a layout .xml file somewhere, but while searching in the core layout xml files, I did not find the original declaration of adminhtml Options/Option.phtml and Options/Type/xxx.phtml in any layout files...

Comment: @Alexglvr if the template file are set from layout then you can set it from layout otherwise you have to set from block.  in your case template are set from block `protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml';`

Comment: Now, I have my New option type present in admin / product / custom options. But When I do "add new option" and select my new defined type, the fields of the option are not shown. The other option types work well... I may have missed something... Is there a js script call somewhere that need to be modified? Browser console returns : "No template was found by selector: null"